# How do I encode a complete URL string in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url, asp.net-mvc-3, urlencode

I get a url string and would like to transform it to a legal http url:

For example:

`"http://one/two/three%four/five#five?six seven"` should turn into `"http://one/two/three%25four/five%23five?six%20seven"`

However, `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` does not help, as it encodes the entire string (including the legal `"://"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this what you want?

```
   Uri uri = new Uri("http://one/two/three%four/#five?six seven");
   string url = uri.AbsoluteUri + uri.Fragment; 
   // url will be "http://one/two/three%25four/#five?six%20seven#five?six%20seven"
```

Comment: Is this solution valid for any URL?

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting and rejoining:

```
string url = "http://one/two/three%four/#five?six seven";
string encodedUrl = "http://" + string.Join("/", url.Substring(7).Split('/').Select(part => HttpUtility.UrlEncode(part)).ToArray());
```